# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator even after no parentheses error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This query is giving me an `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` error.
I checked for the parenthesis but it looks perfectly fine.

```
DELETE FROM delete_test d
WHERE d.trans_date, d.item_nbr, d.serial_nbr IN (
SELECT b.trans_date, b.item_nbr, b.serial_nbr FROM (
SELECT a.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY serial_nbr ORDER BY trans_date) rnk 
FROM delete_test a) b
WHERE rnk <> 1)
;
```

Can anyone help me debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should us extra parenthesis to specify the tuples

try this:

```
DELETE FROM delete_test d
WHERE (d.trans_date, d.item_nbr, d.serial_nbr) IN ((
SELECT b.trans_date, b.item_nbr, b.serial_nbr FROM (
SELECT a.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY serial_nbr ORDER BY trans_date) rnk 
FROM delete_test a) b
WHERE rnk <> 1))
```

---

also after some testing if the tuples is generate by subquery you only need one pair parenthesis, but with plain text like `('a','b','c')` you need two pair, but two pair always work so imo just always use two pair.